# How to make my NuGet package suggested for a class name?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Let's say I have my very specific class name in my package:

```
namespace MyPackageNamespace {

    public class MySpecificClass {
        // code here...
    }

}
```

Then later I have some code like this:

```
var instance = new MySpecificClass();
```

It is marked as error, because I don't have the dependency installed yet. I click it, and...

What happens is VS suggests to create a new class, because it has no clue where to find it.
It could also suggest some wild NuGet package, but of course, not the package I just uploaded to NuGet.

Here's the problem. How to make my packages to be discoverable by VS suggestions?

If the name is very specific, why Visual Studio can't find the package?

I guess it's a matter of metadata for the NuGet package, but I don't know what exact portion of metadata is responsible for my package being suggested for a class name.

Let me be clear here: I CAN search the package explicitly via "manage packages" option in VS. What I try to achieve is my package is automagically suggested and I get "**Install the latest version**" option in context menu for missing class name.

OK, here's how reproduce this Visual Studio behavior:

Create any C# project with Visual Studio.
Now enter this in any method:

```
var p = new MySqlParameter();
```

When `MySqlParameter` is clicked, a light bulb icon appears, when clicked I see among other options an option with NuGet icon and text "Install package MySql.Data", with a submenu "Find and install latest version". It's Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, I don't know if Community Edition does that too.

Lately I moved most of my code base to NuGet and I already have a little trouble recalling in WHICH package my class was.

It would be great if packages could be derived from namespaces referenced with `using` keyword. Like `using MyTools.DataTools;` should suggest getting `MyTools.DataTools` package instead of "remove unnecessary using".

Comment: My guess is that you just need to wait for the nuget service to "index" what's inside your package.

Comment: I think the only times I've ever seen that work is when another project in the same solution already references that package... I could be wrong, though